# Stagehand module withought PEAR

Tags: cakephp, hudson, cakephp-1.3, pear, continuous-integration

I wanna create environment .
CakePHP + Hudson CI env.
but. I don't have a privilege of installing PEAR
so I set Stagehand module on vendor/pear/Stagehand 
but that is not work. :-<

```
 require_once(Stagehand/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory 

 php -d include_path=./:$CAKE/vendors/pear/PEAR/ ./vendors/pear/bin/cakerunner --cakephp-app-path $CAKE/app --log-junit=$CAKE/app/tmp/logs/unittest.xml -R $CAKE/app/tests/cases
 Fatal error: Class 'Stagehand_TestRunner_Runner_RunnerFactory' not found
```

Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

`:$CAKE/vendors/pear/PEAR/` is probably wrong. I guess the `Stagehand/Autoload.php` file is installed in `vendors/pear/Stagehand/Autoload.php`. In that case, use

```
-d include_path=./:$CAKE/vendors/pear/
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the project-specific PEAR environment for a PHP application. In yor case, your project can include the PEAR base system and required packages as follows:

- vendors/pear/PEAR.php
- vendors/pear/bin/cakerunner
- vendors/pear/Stagehand
- vendors/pear/...

or

- app/vendors/pear
- ...

After introducing the project-specific PEAR environment, you can specify the path to into your preload script as:

```
set_include_path('/path/to/project/vendors/pear');
```

Finally, edit the command line for running tests as:

```
/path/to/php /path/to/project/vendors/pear/bin/cakerunner -p /path/to/preload.php --cakephp-app-path=/path/to/project/app --cakephp-core-path=/path/to/project/cake ...
```

[This manual page](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php) explains how to build the project-specific PEAR environment for your project.